STM32 Nucleo64 Serial UART Communication not working in CubeIDE
I have a very simple code on an Arduino I am trying to make work on my STM32f446 Nucleo board. This is the very early stages of the project because I am simply trying to send a hex value/array to a "Gravity: UART MP3 Voice Module with 8MB Flash Memory" in order to play an mp3 audio file. The example code running properly on the Arduino IDE is as Follows:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Serial1(10, 11);  //RX  TX (Signal)type
unsigned char order[4] = {0xAA,0x06,0x00,0xB0}; 

void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(9600); 
  volume(0x08);   //Volume settings 0x00-0x1E
}
void loop() {
  play(0x01);     //Play the specified audio:0x01-file0001
  delay(2000); 
}

// Function Definitions:
void play(unsigned char Track)
{
unsigned char play[6] = {0xAA,0x07,0x02,0x00,Track,Track+0xB3};
 Serial1.write(play,6);
}

void volume( unsigned char vol)
{
 unsigned char volume[5] = {0xAA,0x13,0x01,vol,vol+0xBE};
 Serial1.write(volume,5);
 } 

This works perfectly on an Arduino Uno, but I want to end up with my own custom microcontroller PCB with an STM32 and real C code in the end. This was supposed to just be a test to ensure the MP# module was functioning properly.
Here's what I did on the CubeIDE:
I setup the board using the graphical interface using USART2 (Pins D0 and D1) and set the baud rate to be 9600 just like in the sample code. The Initialization functions were created in the IDE and I did not tweak them at all (maybe I need to IDK). I am using the HAL_UART_Transmit() function to send the character array over UART as I have been instructed to do by many YouTube videos and ChatGPT. I have done a million different versions of this code but I am at my wits end so I got rid of everything I could and simplified it to this:
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  int vol = 0x08;
  volume(vol);

  while (1)
  {
//    play(0x01);
      unsigned char play[6] = {0xAA,0x07,0x02,0x00,0x01,0xB4};          
// hard code the values for play(0x01);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, play, sizeof(play), HAL_MAX_DELAY);    
// hard code the UART Transmit
      HAL_Delay(2000);
   }
}

void play(unsigned char track){
    unsigned char play[6] = {0xAA,0x07,0x02,0x00,track,track+0xB3};
    //Serial1.write(play,6);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, play, sizeof(play), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
void volume(unsigned char vol){
    unsigned char volume[5] = {0xAA,0x13,0x01,vol,vol+0xBE};
    //Serial1.write(volume,5);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, volume, 5, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

Below is also the generated USART Initialization just in case I need to change something on it:
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

I have tried this hard coding the function directly in main as well as using the separate functions but neither seem to work. I can get other things like buttons and LEDs to work fine within this same program with the same setup, but for some reason the UART is not working. I have tries switching the TX and RX wires every time I retry the code to make sure it isn't me accidentally plugging them in backwards.
It is quite difficult to debug as I do not know how to view what is being sent or received on the serial line in CubeIDE and I cannot use printf() to read data on the console Like I an used to in C. If you know a relatively simple way to do either of these things or a different post explaining how to, it would be greatly appreciated.
Any help or suggestions you may have would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

I'd expect cubeIDE can take advantage of that on board STLINK debugger - you don't have to print messages like in ArduinoIDE. Or you can use SWV (uses SWO pin)

How are you connecting this MP3 board to the Nucleo board? Please list all the connections you have between them. How are you powering the MP3 board? Does it seem to be alive? Does it have, for example, an LED to indicate that it is working?

HAL_UART_Init() makes a callback to a function named HAL_UART_MspInit(), which might be in a file named stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c.  That function should enable the UART and GPIO clocks and configure the UART's GPIO pins.  Review or show us that function.

Use a logic analyzer or oscilloscope to probe and monitor the UART signals to ensure it is outputting the correct bits at the intended baud rate.

Read the "UART Communication" section of the STM32 Nucleo-64 boards User Manual.  D0 and D1 are connected to the onboard ST-Link MCU by default.  You would have to change some solder bridges to change that.  It would probably be easier to use USART3 on CN7 pins 1 and 2 (double check that those are the correct pins for your particular Nucleo board).
The USART2 interface available on PA2 and PA3 of the STM32 microcontroller
can be connected to ST-LINK MCU, ST morpho connector, or to ARDUINO® connector.
The choice can be changed by setting the related solder bridges. By default,
the USART2 communication between the target STM32 and ST-LINK MCU is enabled,
in order to support virtual COM port for Mbed™ (SB13 and SB14 ON, SB62 and
SB63 OFF).  If the communication between the target STM32 PA2 (D1) or PA3 (D0)
and shield or extension board is required, SB62 and SB63 must be ON, while SB13
and SB14 must be OFF. In such a case, it is possible to connect another USART
to ST-LINK MCU using flying wires between the ST morpho connector and CN3.
For instance, on NUCLEO-F103RB it is possible to use USART3 available on PC10
(TX) and PC11 (RX). Two flying wires need to be connected as follow:
• PC10 (USART3_TX) available on CN7 pin 1 to CN3 pin RX
• PC11 (USART3_RX) available on CN7 pin 2 to CN3 pin TX


You might be able to test whether USART2 is working correctly via the virtual COM port on your PC.  The ST-LINK MCU on the Nucleo board implements a virtual COM port that you can open with a terminal application on your PC when connected via USB.  Does the data being transmitted over USART2 appear on the terminal via the virtual COM port?  If so then USART2 is working and the problem is that USART2 is connected to the ST-LINK MCU instead of the arduino connector.

Thank you so much for your response, you were completely correct! I had to bridge SB62 and SB63 in order to get USART2 to work with the assigned pins. I did use the pc's COM port with the CoolTerm serial monitor to find out that it was sending all of the correct data and the pins simply were not connected. Hope this thread can help other novice engineers learning STM32 as well. Thank you again!
